# HashSet of SomeObjects and Contains function with int argument

Tags: c#, contains, hashset

Lets say we have class SomeObject with many fields and storing instances in HashSet.
For HashSet comprison we need only one field: int ID, so we have overriden GetHashCode() and Equals() methods.

And now my question is: Can we somehow use hashSet.Contains(someIntVariable) instead of creating whole new object of type SomeObject?
I mean if only int field is important can we use Contains function with int argument given?

I need it to check if object already exists and don't want create whole sample object.

Comment: Why not store the IDs in a `HashSet` instead?

Comment: and what then? I still need objects so i would have to make 2 HashSets one for IDs and second for objects

Comment: What are you actually doing with that hash set?

Comment: Why to use `HashSet` instead of `Dictionary`?

Comment: Adding instances, and searching for them by ID( and we cannot say anything about ID it can be 1 or 234234 )

Comment: Each time you create an instance, put the `ID` only in the `HashSet`, then search by ID. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @PetSerAl to avoid redundancy i may need get ID from instance( but if i cant do anything with HashSet i will probably use Dictionary, that why iam asking here )

Comment: If you actually need to use the object later, use a dictionary.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: and how i get object related to that ID?

Comment: If you need to get object correlated to that ID, use a dictionary. A hashset won't help you with that anyway, whether it stores the custom object or the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashSet` unfortunately does not have the ability to search with a *different* type of objects and get what's stored. This capability could theoretically exist and maybe you can find a collection library on the web that does this.

Best workaround:

Create a separate key struct (e.g. `MyKey`) and use a `Dictionary<MyKey, MyValue>`. That way you can create a key without creating an object.

Alternatively, you could create a wrapper struct that encapsulates either a key or a whole object. You can than cheaply instantiate that struct and pass it to the `HashSet`. I find that to be more complicated than the first idea.